# jQuery.when based on html select

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following HTML:

```
<select id="sURL">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

How do I change the number of input parameters the `jQuery.when` receives based on the option selected from the select box?

For example, if I have the first option selected, I want the `jQuery.when` to load three JSON feeds.  If option two is selected, I want it to load one feed which is not part of the three feeds loaded from the first option.  If the third selectbox option is selected, I want it to load two totally different feeds.

At the moment I have this:

```
$.when(//load feed one, //load feed two).done(// bla bla bla
```

The two feeds are hard coded.  How do I make the feed and the number of feeds more dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make an array of promise objects and apply it to .when.

```
var promiseArr = [];
$.each(someobj,function(){
    ...
    promiseArr.push(promiseObj);
})
$.when.apply($,promiseArr).done(...
```